# Is there a way to extract the url of images my my css file in python?

Tags: python, css

I am trying to get all the urls of images that are used within a css file. For example this is part of my css file:

```
sitewrap {
    width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff url(../images/bg_sitewrap.gif) repeat-y;
}
```

How can receive just the ../images/bg_sitewrap.gif section of it, in python preferably?

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `re.findall` here:

```py
css = """sitewrap {
    width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff url(../images/bg_sitewrap.gif) repeat-y;
}"""

urls = re.findall(r'\burl\((.*?)\)', css)
print(urls)  # ['../images/bg_sitewrap.gif']
```

This answer assumes that you would want to capture every instance of `url(...)` in your CSS script.  If not, then you might need to use a CSS parser/library, before perhaps using regex later in the pipeline to find the URLs.